# OnActionExecution on BaseController and Particular Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I have a BaseController which is like below.

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
{
    
    public string BDynamicConnectionString { get; set; }
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Getting dynamic connectionstring
        this.BDynamicConnectionString = GetDynamicConnetionString(this.BCCompanyId, this.BCCompanyIdentifier);

    }
}
```

I have inherited this base controller in my controller as below.

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    private ClassroomBL objClassroomBL;

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        this.objClassroomBL = ClassObjects.ClassroomBLObject(BDynamicConnectionString);
    }

    public ActionResult FetchDefaultStatuses()
    {
        this.objClassroomBL.FetchDefaultStatuses(145);
        return View();
    }
}
```

As it is visible I have **OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)** on both **BaseController** and **TestController**.
Actually Why I did it like this is I am managing many things in base controller which are needed in each controller inherited from this.

But now I need something like **OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)** on particular controller because I have to initialize object before calling action and object which I have to initialize it uses a property which is initialized in **BaseController**.

If I am adding **OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)** on both then first, controller which is inheriting **BaseController** on this event fires before the BaseController. I know this happening because of OOPS concept.

Is anything else I can add on Controller which fires after **Basecontrollers OnActionExecuting but before action execution of particular controller** .

Thanks!

Comment: Just call `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)` in the first line of overrided method.

Comment: Add base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext); worked..Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use following in the first line of overrided method:

```
base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)
```

See also [`base`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) keyword.